# Using Dialog with youtube API YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent()

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

My app displays list of youtube video, when users select one, I start playing video by using

`YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent()`. After playing video about 2 minutes I want to display a 
Dialog.

***But the problem is, my Dialog display under playing window, so it is hidden until pressing Back key***

***to stop playing video.***

**My question**: *Is there any way to temporarily pause playing video to Show the Dialog?*

Answer (score 0):

I found other solution is start new Activtiy which shows only the popup. But I made this activity to be

Transparent as a popup by using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`